# MS Windows: Change taskbar text

Tags: windows, taskbar

Is there any way to set the text of a taskbar item in Windows XP? I need something on-the-fly that can be set per-instance, not per application. For instance, if I have three Putty windows open, I need to be able to name them in the taskbar.

The applications that I specifically need to rename are Putty and Gvim.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Auto Hot Key is good for this kind of thing, though some self-assembly may be required.

http://www.autohotkey.com/

It has a `WinSetTitle` command that you should be able to use. Windows stores the window title per window, so it should prove possible to individually change the title each window of an application.

Comment: Thank you. I found the example on [this page](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/WinSetTitle.htm) but I am not sure where to put the script. I have installed AutoHotKey. Also, how does one differentiate between two windows with the same title? Thanks.

Comment: I don't know where scripts go; I've just added all my stuff to the script you get when you select "Edit This Script". No idea where it is. As for the window, see AutoHotKey docs for Last Found Window - there's various ways to find a window apart from by its title.

Comment: Thanks for the tips. My first attempt script is 
#n::
WinGetActiveTitle, CurrentWindowTitle
InputBox, NewName, %CurrentWindowTitle%
WinSetTitle, %CurrentWindowTitle%, ,%NewName%
return

Answer (score 1):

for putty you can simple set a default name it in putty setting and dont let it overwrite e.g. current folder

Settings=>Window=>Behaviour=>Window Title 
Settings=>Terminal=>Features=>disable remote-controlled window title changing